# SQL Server (not mysql which uses INTO ) - Save to .csv using a query not manual export to function

Tags: sql-server

I want to be able to run a query every day at the same time and have it automatically save to a location with a specific file name.

Is this possible? Without SSIS or cmdlet or PowerShell, I want to do it all within the query I'm running,

I understand INTO outfile is a mysql syntax, is there an alternative for SQL Server?

Comment: You mentioned not with SSIS, SSIS would make this really easy, is there a reason you cant use SSIS?

Comment: [8 Ways to Export SQL Results To a Text File](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Export/147145/)

Comment: i have miss matched versions and its a live server with business critical functions so i just want to work within the realms of the query im running, can you help?

Comment: Create a SQL Job and schedule it for daily execution.

Comment: how do i do that on ms  sql server management studio? i cant use SSIS

Comment: @CarlHussain Look for `Sql Server Agent` in SSMS Object explorer. Right click on that and select `New-> Job`. Use your `stored procedure` as `steps` and schedule job using `Schedules` section. [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-transact-sql-job-step?view=sql-server-2017) may help.

Comment: i dont have an sql server agent, do you know a way to write it in a query ?

Comment: What do you mean you don't have a sql server agent? How is that even possible? Doing this directly in sql is not that easy. It is actually rather painful which is why things like SSIS are preferred. To do this in t-sql requires a bunch of very painful hurdles. sp_oacreate Yes it can be done but there are so many easier ways to tackle this.

Comment: @CarlHussain Seems that you do not have sufficient permissions. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent-fixed-database-roles?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @SeanLange In SQL Server Express 2008, at least, SQL Server Agent "exists" but immediately stops as soon as it starts.

Comment: @BaconBits interesting. I have never used Express from any version. But I assume it has SSIS, or at least a scaled down version?

Comment: @SeanLange There's no SSIS/SSDT.  IIRC, you can use the Import/Export Wizard, but you can't save the package. And even if you have a saved package, `dtexec.exe` is disabled somehow.  It's *really* stripped down.

Comment: We still don't know what version they are running. But the OP has stated they can't use any of the tools that are actually useful for this sort of thing. Makes me wonder what is going on. This type of contrived restraints generally is an indication of either homework or a misunderstanding of the tools available.

Comment: My main server was made a while ago, MS SQL server management studio express, but i access it on another system that uses SQL  management  studio 2017 the SSIS is installed and i can indeed save a task such as export, and save it in my file system, due to the fact my SSIS version is not the same as my SQL server version so it wont let me, but then when i attempt to  run the saved task, i cannot seem to find a program that does run it, the extension is .dbsx i believe . ive even tries invoke-sqlcmd from powershell but that brings back errors saying it cannot find the table.   thanks

Answer (score 0):

> i understand INTO outfile is a mysql syntax , is there an alternative for ms sql?

I'm assuming you're saying you don't want to use any external tools, including tools that ship with SQL Server itself.  You want something you can run as an SQL query to create the file and without creating an SSIS package (even a package from the Import/Export Wizard).

No.  There are no T-SQL statements supported by MS SQL Server which themselves cause the database engine to write the output directly to a file.

There is no native MS SQL Server equivalent to MySQL's `INTO <outfile>`, PostgreSQL's `COPY (<query>) TO <outfile>`, or Oracle's `spool` command.  As far as MS SQL Server is concerned, writing data to an external file is the entirely responsibility of whatever database client you're using.

The closest you can get would be a CLR function or stored procedure similar to the apparently abandoned https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sqlclrexport#

I suppose you could also use `xp_cmdshell` with `bcp.exe`, but that's kind of cheating around your requirements.

Comment: il take anything to allow me to export when the query is ran, how would i use bcp.exe? ive tried before and it did nothing

Comment: im happy to use the tools given but my mash up of different server makes this difficult and im not experienced enough to upgrade it or change it yet